# Power Bi reporting server custom authentication iframe error

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, power-bi-report-server, custom-authentication

I set up my Power BI reporting server as per the custom authentication steps mentioned in the git repository

https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

Now after setup, I created a few users and am willing to access it from a web application(.net MVC). But I am continuously getting an error check the below screenshot.

[image]

The error I am getting is:-

[image]

After researching a lot, I figured out that Power Bi reporting server configuration is not allowing access from a web application. So I reset the config as per the below screenshot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16

Previous config of the custom header
[image]

New configuration of the custom header
[image]

After implementation of the new config Power bi login page is able to open in the iframe, but when I am passing the credentials reports server workspace is not opening. Can someone please suggest any configuration that I missed or any approach which I need to take so that I can render the report in iframe after the implementation of the custom authentication?

[image]

Comment: Are you _also_ embedding the experience in an IFrame?  Does it work if you navigate directly to the Report Portal?

Comment: If I directly navigate to report portal it redirects to login page

Comment: And after you log in?

Comment: Yes when I directly open the link in chrome or any other browser it works once login I am able to access all reports. When I use iframe I got stuck with login page after passing correct credentials it won’t let me go in the Power BI workspace portal

Comment: I discussed this with Architect regarding this problem once we implement custom authentication with the report server then we need to install certification for the same